# Compound adjective or short phrase to describe something that is affected by an issue

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, business-language

I'm looking for a word, compound adjective or very short phrase that could be used to describe something, such as a parcel delivery, that is affected by an issue.  What I'm looking for is supposed to sound formal or "technical". The only thing I could think of was "issue-affected" but Google showed me I had just made that up or "under issue" but the meaning of that (if it actually has any) is not what I'm looking for.

An example of use of the word would be:

> Deliveries which are complete, pending or *issue-affected*

Thank you very much

Comment: Please read the tag info for single-word requests. "You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used." In this case, I suspect that the word would actually depend on what the particular issue was; but a couple of examples would definitely help.

Comment: Agree with @AndrewLeach about the need for context, but possibly "negative consequence"

Answer (score 1):

(Edited, concerning the comment)

Try [supervene](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supervene) -

> Occur as an interruption or change to an existing situation, to happen in a way that interrupts, stops, or **greatly changes** an existing situation

Also try **influenced** - having its development(procedures, tasks, etc.) , behavior or thought changed or affected

[Influence](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/influence#dataset-business-english) - to affect or change how something or someone develops, thinks or behaves.

In your case ** Deliveries which are complete, pending or supervened. **

Comment: The adjective is supposed to convey that the thing is affected by an issue, without having to specify which. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @Gothbag have a look at it now.

Answer (score 1):

> Deliveries which are complete, pending or *disputed*.

---

> Adj. 1. **disputed** - subject to disagreement and debate –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disputed)

**in dispute** (TFD's Legal Dictionary)

> Disagreed about, in controversy. For example, *This parcel of land is in dispute, claimed by several persons*, or *The origin of this phrase is in dispute.* [Mid-1600s] –[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+dispute)

Deliveries are either complete, pending or *in dispute*.

Answer (score 0):

How about using "indefinitely delayed"?
That way you communicate that there is some issue (and hence indefinite delay) without actually specifying it.